# Are CSS transitions for elements between pages possible?

Tags: html, css, self-hosting

I am able to use the transition attribute to make the width of a div change smoothly when switching from mobile to desktop view. I have two separate pages, index and about. When the user goes to the about page, the width of the div increases. I would like to animate this but I am not sure how since they are on two separate pages.

This is for my personal blog, running Apache2. I've tried using the transition element when the a tag is hovered over but this didn't work and looked weird.

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: width 0.25s;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

When going to a different html page there is no transition animation.

Comment: this is possible In SPA's (single page app) where everything happens within the same page

Comment: You can simulate it with the onload event of the document to add a css class that does the transition || animation to accomplish the same illusion.